# Does Linux use a /etc/inet/netmasks file?

Tags: linux, solaris

How Linux implements subnetting, as opposed to Solaris?

Comment: For Linux users, it might help if you briefly explained how Solaris implements subnetting

Comment: LinuxJournal has an [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6287) on the topic, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the netmasks in linux are set in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts , on a per interface bases.

Where Solaris uses /etc/netmasks to over ride or set the expected netmask, this can be done with the netmask directive in the ifcfg-ethX  script.